# Vimeo issue with video upload. Stuck for ever

Tags: android, ios, video-processing, vimeo, vimeo-api

I have tried uploading video into `vimeo` programmatically. Few of the videos have been stuck for ever. It will be shown in the dashboard like

[image]

Is there any way for finding the cause of the issue ? Video is uploaded via android and iOS. As many of the videos are getting successful, few are only getting stuck

Does anyone went through the above issue or solved ?

**Note**: I have posted in `vimeo` forums and checked many links. None provided the solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem as well. Something I've found that helps is uploading the same file again, in the exact same way. I've noticed that as soon as the 2nd upload completes, the 1st upload completes soon after.

Not exactly sure why, but perhaps there are back-end API limits to Vimeo that might get lifted/resolved if you have more activity in your account, I wonder?

Answer (score 1):

I had this same problem, except I am using a macOS device. This is a little bit of a work-around, but when my upload got stuck, the little upload progress box had a pause button. I clicked that to pause the upload, then unpaused it. It immediately got unstuck and resumed uploading.